# Write a query to find the name of the film which has been rented the fifth-most number of times

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT F.TITLE
FROM FILM AS F
LEFT OUTER JOIN INVENTORY AS I USING (FILM_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN RENTAL AS R USING (INVENTORY_ID)
GROUP BY F.TITLE,R.RENTAL_ID
ORDER BY COUNT(R.RENTAL_ID) DESC   
LIMIT 4,1;
```

I have used the query above to get the fifth-most rented movie in SAKILA DB.
I am having no error with this but am not getting the expected result. 
Please help me out!
[Sakila ERD image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lstQ8.png)

Comment: Why do you group by `F.TITLE, R.RENTAL_ID`? Firstly the title may not be unique, so `F.FILM_ID` would be better. And you don't want to group by `R.RENTAL_ID`, otherwise every film would have a count of 0 or 1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code, it works.

```
select title from film where film_id in (

select film_id from inventory where inventory_id in (
select inventory_id from rental group by inventory_id 
                                order by count(inventory_id) desc ))

limit 4, 1
```

you can  do it using joins too

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT F.TITLE FROM FILM AS F 
INNER JOIN INVENTORY AS I USING (FILM_ID)
INNER JOIN RENTAL AS R USING (INVENTORY_ID)
GROUP BY F.TITLE,R.RENTAL_ID
ORDER BY COUNT(R.RENTAL_ID) DESC   
LIMIT 4,1;
```